# Subsets for each class using weka for microarray data

Tags: weka, subset

How can I do this in explorer of weka:

• for each class, generate subsets with top 2,4,6,8,10,12,15,20,25, and 30 top genes with the highest T-value

my data is in this format:

```
              instances/classes

                  |  |  |
                ----------
                  |  |  |
```

genes/attributes    ----------

```
                  |  |  |
                ----------
                  |  |  |
```

(the rows are attributes and the columns are instances)

Answer (score 0):

Weka is not suitable for such subset generation, you may accomplish this feat but it will not be easy. I suggest put your data to other program and generate your subsets, after that use weka for classification and clustering which are weka's main point.

You can use R/Matlab/Python or an SQL database for this subset generation.